# How to import the generated activity class androidannotation

Tags: android, android-annotations

I just started playing around with android annotation.

I know that when I do @Eactivity, another ActivityName_ class is generated instead.

Now, in my code, i have ActivityName.this written somewhere. But when i change it into ActivityName_.this, my compiler starts to complain that it is not recognized. My question is how do I import the proper ActivityName_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not have to change all the class names to the generated class name. In this case, writing `ActivityName.this` will work just fine. Actually you only have to use the generated class names for `Activity`s in two places:

1. in the manifest where you declare the `Activity`
2. in your intents, where you start an `Activity` (and you can use the generated `Intent` builder: `ActivityName_.intent(this).start()`

The generated classes will be available after you compile (make) the project. So please compile the classes first.

Comment: Thanks for the help!